# Can I backup and restore a Firestore database?

Tags: firebase, import, google-cloud-firestore, export, database-backups

I have a Firestore db and want to make an update to a field in all documents of a collection. Like the cautious programmer I am I reckon something might go wrong so I want to make a backup of this collection. But I cannot find anywhere an option in the Firebase console to do this.
So my question is: can I export a collection and import it again using te FB console? I'm on a free Firebase Spark plan

Thanks,

Marc